# Will you introduce (or do you already have) a deletion review process?

Tags: feature-request, review, deleted-answers

I recently contributed an answer to a question on a Stack Exchange site which clearly helped the OP solve the problem they were having, and in the easiest possible way, but did so using a free third party tool.

My answer was deleted supposedly because "This is being removed since it has the appearance of being an advertisement for a third-party product or service instead of answering the question being asked."

Other platforms have a peer review process for deletions. Are you planning to introduce something like that at any point?

Or, if such a review process already exists, is there any way to make it more transparent to all?

I gather that users with 10k+ reputation have access to a list of all deleted posts. What would be their motivation for reviewing these?

Otherwise it's a bit hard for newbies like me not feel completely at the mercy of the whims of high reputation users. And without recourse.

Comment: Ironically a high reputation user came along and whimsically down-voted my question..

Answer (score 8):

The problem with so-called ['link-only answers'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/295232) is that they become useless once the link breaks, and that it's often hard to verify if somebody is doing illegal promotion for the product. Therefore, they are deleted quite soon, before these problems occur. Nothing is more disappointing than having a problem, somebody is claiming to have the perfect solution and when you click on it, you get a 404. I remember those days, the days before Stack Overflow ...

> I gather that users with 10k+ reputation have access to a list of all deleted posts.

Only their own posts, and a short list of recently deleted posts which only a few people are looking at.

> Are you planning to introduce something like that at any point?

The procedure here would be to edit your answer so that

- it's clear that you don't have any affiliation with the product
- the answer gives a brief description how to exactly solve the problem

and flag the post for moderator attention, explaining that you've addressed the problems with your answer and want to have it undeleted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Glorfindel. Yes, I too have been frustrated by non-maintained link-only-answers with broken links. However, some link-only answers can also be very useful. 
The tool I linked to (for automatically creating .htaccess code for temporary and permanent site redirections) is one of the most useful things I've discovered on Stack Overflow. The OP in this case specifically asked for help with .htaccess, and short of a four page tutorial on regex, this tool was the most useful thing he could have been given. And yes, I explained in the answer exactly how to use it.

Comment: Happen to have a link to your answer?

Comment: @Glorfindel It's on Webmasters, so it wouldn't do you much good. :P https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/108193/redirecting-domains-sub-domains-and-single-pages-on-siteground/118157#118157

Comment: Ah, makes sense.